# How to get values of check-boxes in nested ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api2

I have a nested `ng-repeat`, first one as a title of department, second one shows employees that belong to this department. I hope to know how to capture or get their values if I have multiple checked departments keys and multiple employees keys, then send them to a web API. Thanks in advance.

The HTML is like

```
<fieldset id="field3">
   <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="e in empdepts | groupBy:'dep_LDesc'">
           <td>
               <label ng-click="showContent = !showContent"></label>
               <details ng-open="showContent">
               <summary><input type="checkbox" ng-model="e[0].master" ng-click="group(e[0].master,e)" /> {{e[0].dep_LDesc}}</summary>
               <div ng-repeat="employee in e">
               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.details" > {{employee.Sname}} 
               </div>
               </details>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>

   <hr />
   <table>
       <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="all" ng-click="selectall(all)"  /> All Departments</td> 
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="self"/> Self Services </td> 
       </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

The Controller is like

```
Assign.controller("AssignController", function ($scope, Assignments) {

LoadEmpDepts();
function LoadEmpDepts() {
    Assignments.getempdepts().then(function (response) {
        $scope.empdepts = (response.data);
        console.log($scope.empdepts);
    })
}

$scope.group = function (m, x) {
    angular.forEach(x,function (cv) {
        cv.details = m;
    })
   return m;
}

$scope.selectall = function (value) {
    $scope.master = value;
    angular.forEach($scope.empdepts, function (cv) {
        cv.details = value;
        cv.master = value;
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **Angular Copy** which send only that checkbox value which is modified. And You need to push all the check boxes value in array.

[See Example in Official Documentation of AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

**Push Code Example:**

In controller

File Name: 1.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myController",function($scope){
$scope.newArray =[];
$scope.arrayPush =function()
{
    console.log("new1");
    $scope.newArray.push({name:$scope.name});
    console.log($scope.newArray);
}
})
```

In Views

File Name: **1.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<p>Input something in the input box:</p> 
<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">
<button ng-click="arrayPush()">Test Button</button>
</div>
</body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
```

Try this Code.. If you get any error then please mention in comment..

Thanks...

**Answer Updated**

Comment: Thanks lot for your reply, i will try to use it then check the answer

Comment: Thanks the copy works,Kindly do you have an example for the Push

Comment: Hi Hassan, I update Answer for You ... If you get any error then please mention in comment.. Thank You...

Comment: Thank you for reply. unfortunately it didnt work, i think because the  pushArray() method runs when the page loads.

Comment: Hello Hassan, I again modified code for you.. Please Try This... If doesn't work again mention in Comments... Thank You and sorry for earlier wrong code...